# Google Chrome inspect devices?

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, inspect

I'm trying to inspect device from google chrome

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Basically i'm not able to recognize my connected device. Instead i'm getting this
[image]

I did

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

It actually restarted and did not work

How to actually inspect element for the devices?

Comment: do u open the USB debug? and u open chrome in ur device, then open  any  website, is it change?

Comment: @周恩旭 Did u mean, I have to enable USB debugging in the device. And open google chrome in my device? what exactly you mean?

Comment: yes, u should enable USB debugging, and open chrome and open a url, you will see the inspect have the website info if u connect successful

Comment: @周恩旭  I have did the above steps. But still i'm unable to connect, as u can see the above attached image

Comment: sorry, my 3 devices are successful, I dont know why are u failed. what do u run `adb devices` command shows, have any device?

Comment: @周恩旭 yes `adb devices` is showing my device

Comment: People who downvoted would likely to provide sufficient reasons for doing it

Comment: do you check the `Discover USB device`?

Comment: Where do i check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150382/discussion-between-matarishvan-and-).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. Please try the below methods

1. Go to your device - Developer options - click on `Revoke USB debugging autorizations` and enable developer options and USB debugging. This will again ask `accept debugging session on the device` on your device.
2. Inspect will only work on **debug mode** and not on **release mode**. If you are using `android studio` you can change like below in the screenshot.

[image]